# Trouble with UIScrollView in iOS 8 GM

Tags: user-interface, sdk, uiscrollview, ios8

I'm developing and iOS app which I started with iOS 7 and now tried to migrate to iOS 8. Everything works nicely except UIScrollViews. My app has a navigation bar and it seems to affect to UIScrollViews. Indeed, the content inside the view is pulled down the approximate space that a navigation bars occupies. The weird thing is that the same app running on iOS 7 doesn't cause any sort of problem related to that.

I've made a simple code to test if the problem was my app, but the problem is still there. Here it is my code:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-65)];
scroll.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
scroll.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
[self.view addSubview:scroll];

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searching1.png"]];
[scroll addSubview:image];
image.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 100);
```

And that's the result, as you can see the image is not at point (0, 100):

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know how to deal with this problem. Moreover, iOS 8 is now in GM, so I don't know if this is a real bug or a SDK change.

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused by the propety

> self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

Turns out that in iOS 7 it was automatically set to false, but now in iOS it is true by default. So setting it explicitly to false solved the problem and the app is running well in both platforms.